# Timer is giving me random numbers in return

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

```
func executeSpawningStar(startPosition: CGPoint) {
        print(startPosition)
}
```

This function gets executed by this lines:

```
  gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(executeSpawningStar), userInfo: (startPosition: 0, 0), repeats: true)
```

This is the print:

```
(1421871380267.49, 9.22337203685478e+18)
(1421902263851.49, 9.22337203685478e+18)
(1421902263851.49, 9.22337203685478e+18)
```

How is this even possible when I specific say any random number? I see any number inserted returns this very random numbers. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing this all wrong. The parameter to the `executeSpawningStart` function must be the timer. It can't be anything else. You then get the start position from the timer's `userInfo` property.

So you need:

```
func executeSpawningStar(_ timer: Timer) {
    if let startPosition = timer.userInfo as? CGPoint {
        print(startPosition)
    }
}
```

This assumes that the `userInfo` you setup when creating the timer is actually a `CGPoint` (which I based on your original `executeSpawningStar` method.

But in your call to `scheduledTimer...` you are not actually passing a `CGPoint` to the `userInfo` parameter. It appears to be some sort of tuple. You probably want to pass `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` instead of `(startPosition: 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

@rmaddy's answer is correct, but if your deployment target is iOS 10.0+ (or macOS 10.12+ or tvOS 10.0+ or watchOS 3.0+), you can use the version of `scheduledTimer` that takes a block instead of a selector, and avoid using `userInfo` at all. Example:

```
var point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    print(point)
    point.x += 1
}
```